# SmartMX Hybrid Card - How to access MIFARE Classic

Tags: smartcard, mifare, apdu, pcsc, contactless-smartcard

I have a bunch of hybrid smart cards with SmartMX chip (`smartmx-m3b.03.d3-NX212A` to be exact), which contain a MIFARE Classic 4k. I have been trying to access the MIFARE portion of the cards, and while doing so on Android is rather trivial task of accessing the `android.nfc.tech.MifareClassic` tag, I have no idea of how to do so in Windows. Should I be looking for PCSC Reader specific commands to access MIFARE Classic on this card? Or should I look for a SmartMX chip specific APDU to wrap commands for MIFARE classic?

Comment: Is your card a hybrid card (i.e. a SmartMX with contact interface is packed together with a MIFARE Classic contactless chip into one plastic card) or a dual-interface card (i.e. a SmartMX with MIFARE Classic emulation and both a contact and a contactless interface)?

Comment: Do you want to access the MIFARE Classic memory over the contact or the contactless interface when accessing the card from Windows?

Comment: @MichaelRoland It's a dual interface card. SmartMX with MIFARE Classic emulation. I want to access MIFARE Classic over the contactless interface, accessing the card from various readers and operating systems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This heavily depends on the smartcard reader that you are using. First of all, as [mictter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25737994/2425802) pointed out, your reader has to support MIFARE Classic technology (which basically means that you are stuck with contactless readers based on some NXP chipset, or readers that (despite NXP's licensing policy on MF Classic reader technology) implement MIFARE Classic reader functionality).

Next, you will likely run into a problem with automatic protocol activation of the reader. Most PS/SC readers I used so far (e.g. HID Omnikey 5321) will automatically perform protocol activation up to the highes available protocol layer. For a SmartMX chip that exposes both MIFARE Classic and ISO-DEP (ISO/IEC 14443-4, with ISO/IEC 7816-4 APDUs on top) protocols over its contactless interface, this means that the reader will automatically perform the ISO-DEP link activation. This effectively disables access through the MIFARE Classic protocol (as the MF Classic protocol operates on top of a lower layer -> ISO/IEC 14443-3).

Therefore, you basically have two options:

- Use an applet that speaks APDUs on the one side and accesses the MIFARE Classic memory area<sup>1</sup> on the other side. NXP provides a ready-made applet for this that may or may not be enabled for the contactless interface. Also NXP provides an API that you could use within your own applet<sup>2</sup> to access the MIFARE Classic memory area<sup>1</sup>. So you could write your own custom applet
- Force the smartcard reader to activate only to ISO/IEC 14443-3 protocol layer in order to access the card as MIFARE Classic card. Depending on your reader this could be something between trivial and impossible to do. Some readers, like the afore mentioned HID Omnikey reader, support changing the level of automatic protocol activation through a registry setting (or through the HID Workbench tool). Some readers (e.g. the ACR122U in its older variant) permit you to perform a manual enumeration and activation of contactless cards, where you can freely choose the activated protocol layer. The PC/SC specification, in its current version (which means that those features might not be supported by some/many readers), defines a SWITCH_PROTOCOL command that can be used to force manual activation of a contactless card up to a user-defined protocol level (see the [PC/SC 2 specification, Part 3, Supplemental Document 2 - Contactless ICCs](http://www.pcscworkgroup.com/specifications/specdownload.php) on how this command works).

---

<sup>1</sup>) Read either as "MIFARE Classic memory area" or as "virtual MIFARE Classic card". I did not find much information on that chip type. Depending on how new this chip and its software is, instead of MIFARE Classic memory area, the chip might (I doubt that though) be capable of managing true virtual MIFARE Classic cards according to the new version of the MIFARE4Mobile specification.

<sup>2</sup>) I assume that the SmartMX you are using runs JCOP OS and that you can install arbitrary Java Card applets.

Comment: Thanks for very detailed answer. I did a little digging of my own and found out that protocol selection is basen on card's SAK value.

Comment: Does anyone found a solution to do the protocol switch with a SCL3711?

Answer (score 0):

Since MIFARE Classic is a proprietary technology, you'll need that the reader supports it. For example, only Android phones with NFC controllers made by NXP are able to access it (my own Nexus 5 has a Broadcom one, so I cannot access `android.nfc.tech.MifareClassic`).

A suitable workaround is MIFARE4Mobile: you can send GlobalPlatform APDUs to a JavaCard applet (usually provided by NXP, but there are other implementations) and the applet, called "Service Manager", controls the MIFARE Classic element on the card.

Comment: Both my readers support MIFARE Classic. But I have no idea how to tell the reader to treat the card as MIFARE Classic instead of a _smart card_.

Comment: I'm afraid you will have to look at the reader's documentation. Some readers I've used have APDU-like commands, others have proprietary APIs. As far as I know, PCSC does not have Mifare Classic commands.

Comment: My readers have APDU like commands for MIFARE classic cards, but those commands don't work with hybrid cards. Apparently with a hybrid card, all commands are processed by the _smarter_ chip of the card

Comment: In our startup we deal with this, but I don't know whether it'd be good manners to put a link here in Stack Overflow. It is probably necessary to enable the MIFARE Classic "emulation" by instantiating a Service Manager first. Look for the Mifare4Mobile v1.01 spec in NXP's website - the spec explains how to do it- and see if you can get the Mifare4Mobile applet from your card supplier.

Comment: I don't think it is necessary to instantiate the Service Manager though - but the MIFARE Classic functionality has to be enabled at pre-personalization time. Did you pre-perso the cards yourself?

Comment: Yes I did per-personalize the cards myself. As a matter of fact, the cards are not fused yet. And MIFARE Classic is enabled on the cards because I can access them as MIFARE Classic on Android